# Ubuntu 17.10 takes 5+min. time to boot

Tags: boot, 17.10

Fresh install, login in to the system, restarted and then this :
Just stuck on ubuntu loading screen for 5+minutes, screen turns black i see acer logo again and then boots "normaly" systemd-analyze blame doesn't show anything neither

Comment: It's hard to guess, but sometimes it takes all that time trying to connect the Network Interface...check it and make sure it's configured properly.

Comment: I'm really sorry to ask, but how can i check it ?

Comment: `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` and the basic configuration looks like this.....`auto lo` -NewLine-
`iface lo inet loopback`
...reboot and you should be fine.

Comment: it wrote me the basics as you described, should i restart or replace something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is related to a network issue then follow this checklist.

- Ensure that IPV6 (or IPV4) is NOT disabled. If one is disabled then the bootup process continues after a network timeout after exactly 2 minutes. Disabling is typically done in the config file /etc/sysctl.conf (searchfor: disable_ipv). If you find such lines then remove those lines and reboot.
- Assuming that you use DHCP to get an IP Address then this is the default netplan configuration file. Perhaps this config file was changed recently?

> nano /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

- This is the default content of another network config file

> nano /etc/network/interfaces

```
# /etc/network/interfaces -- configuration file for ifup(8), ifdown(8)
# Generated by debian-installer.
# The loopback interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

- You might see that is wrong in the NetworkManager by inspecting its configuration. Open a Terminal window on the Ubuntu Desktop and run these commands:

> ```
> sudo nmcli networking
> sudo nmcli general status
> sudo nmcli device status
> sudo nmcli device wifi list
> sudo nmcli connection show
> sudo ip address show
> ```

Hopefully this helps.